# Excel; How to find character and give matching description

Tags: excel, find, match

I have a table with clients and specific markers for each shop:

| Client | Markers | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | B,D,K,M,f,n,,+ |  |
| Max | B,D,J,K,M,f,i,n,+ |  |
| Ted | D,i,a,1,J,Y,K,M |  |
| Maria | C,D,J,K,M,n |  |
| Alex | A,D,K,M,f,i,n |  |
| Tom | A,D,K,M,f,m,o,y,+ |  |
| Richard | R,D,J,K,M,f,i,n |  |
| X | A,D,K,M,f,n |  |
| Red | A,D,K,M,f,i,n,+ |  |
| John | C,D,F,K,M,f,i,n,4 |  |
| Lex | T,D,a,1,4,T,K,M |  |
| Ted | D,a,1,T,K,M |  |
| Jane | D,a,1,T,K,M |  |

Another table contains the Locations:

| marker | desc |
| --- | --- |
| A | New York |
| B | Amsterdam |
| C | London |
| H | Tokyo |
| Q | Paris |
| R | Vancouver |
| T | Sydney |
| Y | Auckland |

Now I want to fill first table with locations but going wrong when first marker isn't the location marker. I used: `=VLOOKUP([@Markers],TableLocations[marker],1,TRUE)`, I've tried the MATCH function but this gives the wrong number again.
So only works fine when first character in the marker column matches the marker in the location table.

Comment: What would be for multiple markers like you have `B,D` in first row? Do you want multiple location or only first marker location?

Comment: Sorry should not be multiple locations C is London :)

Comment: Can you please try my answer and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

To find only for first marker location from comma separated values from each cell in first column, you can use-

```
=XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(B2,","),$G$2:$G$9,$H$2:$H$9)
```

For multiple location try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($H$2:$H$9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH($G$2:$G$9,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B2,",")),0))))
```

For dynamic spill array at one go, try-

```
=BYROW(B2:B14,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($H$2:$H$9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH($G$2:$G$9,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(x,",")),0))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm I tried your first solution. Works fine when first marker is found but not on other rows when location marker is further down in list.

Comment: Also needs to case-specific. a is not New York.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using tables and structured references (which you can change to normal addressing if you preferred, but the former are more dynamic).

*In your comments you indicated there would be only one location per client; if you need more than one, please clarify*

***Edit: corrected missing structured reference***

```
=INDEX(Location[desc],AGGREGATE(14,6,BYCOL(EXACT(TEXTSPLIT([@Markers],","),Location[marker]),LAMBDA(arr,XMATCH(TRUE,arr))),1))
```

[image]

*Note: One can get case-sensitive matches using either `EXACT` or `FIND` functions. But, because of the null string in the list in your first row (note the doubled-comma in the Markers), `FIND` will always return a match for that, potentially causing an incorrect result*